# pyparsing issue

Tags: python, parsing, expression, pyparsing, postfix-operator

Right now I have just started to use `pyparsing` to parse simple postfix expressions. At the moment, I got this far:

```
from pyparsing import *
integer = Word(nums)
op = Word("+-*/^", max=1)
space = Word(" ")
expr = Word(nums)+space+Word(nums)+space+op
parsed = expr.parseString("3 4 *")
print parsed
```

But when I run it, it prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "star_parse.py", line 6, in <module>
    parsed = expr.parseString("3 4 *")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyparsing-1.5.5-py2.6.egg/pyparsing.py", line 1100, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:( ) (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: `integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))`  - will do string->int conversion at parse time so that when working with the results, the ints will already be converted to integers.

Comment: nice! wow. the author of pyparsing! cool!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

White space is handled by default.  There is also the handy `oneOf`:

```
from pyparsing import *
integer = Word(nums)
op = oneOf('* + - / ^')
expr = integer + integer + op
parsed = expr.parseString("3 4 *")
print parsed
```

Comment: how would I go about parsing nested expressions?

Comment: or a variable amount of `integer`s before an `op`?

Comment: For nested expressions, you'd need a Forward: `expr = Forward(); term = integer | Group('(' + expr + ')'); expr << (OneOrMore(term) + op)`

Comment: Forward creates a placeholder so that you can use an expression before you've fully defined it. Then, when you are ready to actually define the expression, do so using the `<<` operator. This is needed when you have a recursive grammar - note that term is defined using expr, and expr is defined using term. Any time you have nested expressions, you'll end up using a Forward (or one of the wrappers around Forward, like operatorPrecedence or nestedExpr).

Comment: Without the parentheses, then your expression becomes left-recursive: term is an expr, an expr starts with a term, which could be an expr, which starts with a term, which... pyparsing doesn't like this.

Comment: Instead of a recursive expression, just parse `ZeroOrMore(integer | op)`, with parse actions that push each integer onto a stack. On an op, pop the two integers, perform the op, and push the result.  If the stack has a single entry at the end of processing, it is the result, otherwise there is a mismatch of integers and operations.

Answer (score 4):

White space is ignored by pyparser. You can explicitly test for whitespace by using the White class.

However the expression you are probably looking for is:

```
expr = integer + integer + op
```

http://packages.python.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.White-class.html

Comment: Nice answer - unf. the link points to some pretty old docs, I need to get some current pyparsing docs online...

Comment: Yeah, I tried the link to the online docs on http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation , but it appeared broken.

Comment: @Paul But it would also appear to be you're the pyparsing author, so you probably already knew that.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in, I'm glad not to be the only one to post pyparsing answers.

Comment: PyPI now hosts project docs, so I updated the URL in the answer to point to the latest and greatest.